# Finding variance of a sample

Tags: probability

I have been looking at one question, here it is:

$X \sim U(0,a)$, we are then told that $X_1$ and $X_2$ form a sample and asked to show that variance of the sample is $\frac{1}{4}(X_1 - X_2)^2$. $X_1$ and $X_2$ are random draws of $X$. I find this question weird in many ways.

I tried approaching it by looking at covariance of $X_1,X_2$. But that is not how one should solve it. If I set $Y = \frac{X_1+X_2}{2}$ and look for varaince of that, it does not seem like that would be the right answer. And even if I did, then I would have something like:

$$\mathbb{V}[Y]=\mathbb{E}[\left( \frac{X_1+X_2}{2}^2\right)] - ...$$

Which I have no clue what it would be:

$$\frac{1}{2a}\int_0^{a} (X_1+X_2) \ d?$$

I also considered quadratic variation, which appears to be almost the answer. Quadratic variation is defined as:

$$V^N = \sum_{i=0}^n |f_i - f_{i-1}|^N$$

Where $f_i$ and $f_{i-1}$ are just some consecutive observations of some variable. So:

$$V^2 = |X_2-X_1|^2 = (X_1-X_2)^2$$

But quadratic variation is not variance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [sample variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sample_variance) is a random variable defined as: $$\frac1{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar X)^2$$

where: $$\bar X:=\frac1{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$

Work this out for $n=2$.